# What does the filesystem cache do in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, git, cache

The [Diagnosing why Git is so slow](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Diagnosing-why-Git-is-so-slow) article has this interesting item in it:

> ### Enable the filesystem cache
>
> Windows' filesystem layer is inherently different from Linux' (for which Git's filesystem access is optimized). As a workaround, Git for Windows offers a filesystem cache which accelerates operations in many cases, after an initial "warm-up". You can activate the filesystem cache per-repository:
>
> `git config core.fscache true`

If I enable this option in Git, what actually changes? What does the filesystem cache in Windows 7 look like, and what is being cached? What does the "initial warm-up" entail?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is what `git config --help` says:

> **core.fscache**
>   Enable additional caching of file system data for some operations.
>
> Git for Windows uses this to bulk-read and cache lstat data of entire directories (instead of doing lstat file by file).

Instead of doing many file-system requests git will do only one request to get information about all files in directory.

More technical description can be found in commit that introduced `fscache`:
[Win32: add a cache below mingw's lstat and dirent implementations](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/88a0090d1a8172ed27beb8f18c450b81f5c12fff)

> Checking the work tree status is quite slow on Windows, due to slow lstat
>   emulation (git calls lstat once for each file in the index). Windows
>   operating system APIs seem to be much better at scanning the status
>   of entire directories than checking single files.
>
> Add an lstat implementation that uses a cache for lstat data. Cache misses
>   read the entire parent directory and add it to the cache. Subsequent lstat
>   calls for the same directory are served directly from the cache.
>
> Also implement opendir / readdir / closedir so that they create and use
>   directory listings in the cache.
>
> The cache doesn't track file system changes and doesn't plug into any
>   modifying file APIs, so it has to be explicitly enabled for git functions
>   that don't modify the working copy.

Comment: Does "The cache doesn't track file system changes and doesn't plug into any modifying file APIs" mean that if you have modified your work tree (e.g. during development) `git status` doesn't see the change?

Comment: @Antonio: no, since the cache only lives during a single git command invocation. So the only changes it could conceivably miss is changes that happen *while you're running `git status`* (but those are not guaranteed anyway, due to the inherent race condition).

Comment: thanks for the clarification!